# Apache 2 Permission for Download Data

Tags: permissions, download, apache-http-server, webserver

I set up an Apache2 webserver on the raspberry Pi (Raspbian - Realy close to Debian), and I wanted to download a File from the website. In order to do that, I copied a video file (`.avi`) to the `/var/www/` folder and tried to access it over the website. It told me

```
Forbidden You don't have permission to access /HIMYM.avi on this server.
```

I can open all html files but no other files. How can I change that ?

Comment: Just give the file read permission to all users.  Only the owner would need write permission and really thats only at the folder level.

Answer (score 2):

The file may not have read permission. From the Terminal,

```
chmod 775 /var/www/HIMYM.avi
```

Comment: Read permission is enough: chmod 644. With 775 you are giving execute permission and write permission to the group (both not necessary)

Comment: Thank u ! it works realy great. ( chmod 644 /var/www/HIMYM.avi ) ... 
but can i do the same thing with an hole folder. i dont want to give each file at once that i has permission?

Comment: oh i found the solution. its : sudo chmod 755 /var/www/